# Was bedeutet „langsam“ in diesem Kontext?

Tags: meaning

Wenn man

> Gehen wir langsam (…)?

oder

> Kommen wir langsam zum Schluß …

hört, welche Rolle spielt denn *langsam*? Ist es etwas Entscheidendes oder kann man es einfach ignorieren? Ich vermute nur, es übt weichend auf den Satz aus, bin aber mir nicht sicher. Im Wörterbuch steht nur das Adjektiv bzw. das Adverb. Nur ob es buchstäblich gemeint wird (im Sinne *keine Sorge, keine Eile*), das weiß ich noch nicht.

Comment: In Wörterbüchern steht häufig nur das Adjektiv. Das Adverb (was ja in aller Regel unverändert ist) lässt sich aber immer davon ableiten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es ist eine höfliche Untertreibung.

Das "langsam" drückt Ungeduld aus. In Wirklichkeit bedeutet es genau das Gegenteil:

"Ich habe jetzt keine Lust mehr, mich weiter damit zu beschäftigen. Es reicht mir! Ich hoffe, wir können dies so schnell wie möglich beenden!"

Es kommt auch auf den Kontext an.

Wenn dies z. B. ein Lehrer zu seinen Schülern um 13:00 Uhr sagt, dann drückt er seine stille Freude darüber aus, dass nun bald Feierabend ist. In anderen Fällen bedeutet es "Gleich knallt's!"

Comment: Genau, insbesondere zeigt "Es reicht mir langsam!" an, daß der Sprecher gleich explodieren wird. Dieses Signal ist sozusagen die letzte Chance, Schlimmeres zu verhindern.

Comment: Also, wärend meines Deutschkurses mussten wir Prüfungen ablegen. Die Lehrerin sagte denjenigen, die noch nicht fertig waren: "Wir kommen langsam zum Ende" oder so was. Deswegen dachte ich mir, es wäre etwas eher *Nettes, Höffliches*. Stimmt anscheinend aber nicht ganz. Darüberhinaus ist es noch kontextabhängig.

Comment: @c.p. Doch, es *ist* höflicher als "Gib jetzt sofort dene Arbeit ab, sonst ...!", aber nicht weniger bestimmt.

Comment: Ich denke es kommt schon deutlich auf den Kontext an. "Kommt langsam zum Ende" in einer Klausur kann das Signal sein, dass jetzt noch z. B. 15 min sind: Noch keine Hektik notwendig, aber schonmal der Hinweis. Am Ende dann "Schreibt den Satz noch zu Ende und sammelt die Arbeiten ein."

Comment: @c.p., you need to take this with a grain of salt - I'd say that it's *primarily* context dependent. I use this pretty often - exactly in the "softening" sense you mention in your question. Of course it *can* also express impatience, but I'm pretty sure you'll be able to tell from the context, e.g. you and your SO are out with friends. "Gehen wir langsam" fits (and will be used) when you're having a great time, but one of you has to get up early next day, *and* when you're bored stiff and just want to go home.

Comment: @Mac That was worth an answer. That's what actually solves my doubt, cool...

Answer (score 7):

*Langsam* wird hier im Sinne von *allmählich* oder *endlich* verwendet. Die Aussage ist also

> Können wir endlich gehen?

oder

> Kommen wir allmählich zum Schluss